# Migration from JIRA to a file

Tags: jira

My organization is moving away from JIRA and I've been given the task to archive or get all our JIRA tickets out ASAP. How can I do migration into any file/doc? any idea please as I can't find useful resource from the internet

Answer (score 0):

Well you can perform an JIRA Backup that will generate you a backup which can be used to later restore but doesn't make it that useful in terms of viewing.

Or you can perform an issue search and from the results perform some sort of export:

[image]

Really depends on the number if issues you have, how custom your JIRA is and what useful data you wish to retain.